# I get ""Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/api/tutorials: 0 Unknown Error"" instead of actual error message in Angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 16 HttpClient to send requests to external services. It is a very standard setup:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Tutorial } from '../models/tutorial.model';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/tutorials';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TutorialService {
  headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<never> {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
    // You can throw an error or return an observable here
    return throwError('Something went wrong'); // Example of returning an observable with an error message
  }
  getAll(): Observable<Tutorial[]> {
    return this.http.get<Tutorial[]>(baseUrl, this.httpOptions).pipe(catchError((e: any) => this.handleError(e)));
  }

  get(id: any): Observable<Tutorial> {
    return this.http.get<Tutorial>(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, { headers: this.headers });
  }
```

The problem is, when the request fails I see a generic Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/api/tutorials: 0 Unknown  Error message in the console.
[image]

Comment: status 0 could be a blocked request, what do you network tab say ? On the server do you receive the request or is completely stopped before reaching ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate your error by reusing your service class.
In my case, the error happens because no server is listening on `localhost:8080`.

[image]

Since this is the most likely scenario, you should check this first.

You could use a separate HTTP client like cURL to test your server:

```bash
curl localhost:8080
```